# cmd reading url as string of commands

Tags: windows, batch-file, url, command, echo

I am trying to make a batch file that opens multiple urls via wget and then extracts pictures from them based on a key word in the html. The problem I am having is the way the url is written the batch seems to think it is a list of commands that do not exist. the url is formatted as such http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?page=2&output=spoiler&method=visual&action=advanced&set=%5B%22ORI%22%5D

I need to get the url to be recognized as a url and have a variable to change one part of the url at the point that says ORI.

This is how the variable is being set I am new to arrays so I have probably done this the hard way.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set array[0]=ARN
set array[1]=ATQ
set array[2]=LEG
set array[3]=DRK
set array[4]=FEM
set array[5]=HML
set array[6]=ICE
set array[7]=ALL
set array[8]=CSP
set array[9]=MIR
set array[10]=VIS
set array[11]=WTH
set array[12]=TMP
set array[13]=STH
set array[14]=EXO
set array[15]=USG
set array[16]=ULG
set array[17]=UDS
set array[18]=MMQ
set array[19]=NEM
set array[20]=PCY
set array[21]=INV
set array[22]=PLS
set array[23]=APC
set array[24]=ODY
set array[25]=TOR
set array[26]=JUD
set array[27]=ONS
set array[28]=LGN
set array[29]=SCG
set array[30]=MRD
set array[31]=DST
set array[32]=5DN
set array[33]=CHK
set array[34]=BOK
set array[35]=SOK
set array[36]=RAV
set array[37]=GPT
set array[38]=DIS
set array[39]=TSP
set array[40]=TSB
set array[41]=PLC
set array[42]=FUT
set array[43]=LRW
set array[44]=MOR
set array[45]=SHM
set array[46]=EVE
set array[47]=ALA
set array[48]=CON
set array[49]=ARB
set array[50]=ZEN
set array[51]=WWK
set array[52]=ROE
set array[53]=SOM
set array[54]=MBS
set array[55]=NPH
set array[56]=ISD
set array[57]=DKA
set array[58]=AVR
set array[59]=RTR
set array[60]=GTC
set array[61]=DGM
set array[62]=THS
set array[63]=BNG
set array[64]=JOU
set array[65]=KTK
set array[66]=FRF
set array[67]=DTK
set array[68]=BFZ
set array[69]=OGW
set array[70]=SOI
set array[71]=EMN
set array[72]=CHR
set array[73]=ATH
set array[74]=BRB
set array[75]=BTD
set array[76]=DKM
set array[77]=DPA
set array[78]=EMA
set array[79]=EVG
set array[80]=DD2
set array[81]=DDC
set array[82]=DDD
set array[83]=DDE
set array[84]=DDF
set array[85]=DDG
set array[86]=DDH
set array[87]=DDI
set array[88]=DDJ
set array[89]=DDK
set array[90]=DDL
set array[91]=DDM
set array[92]=DDN
set array[93]=DD3
set array[94]=DDO
set array[95]=DDP
set array[96]=DDQ
set array[97]=DDR
set array[98]=DDS
set array[99]=DRB
set array[100]=V09
set array[101]=V10
set array[102]=V11
set array[103]=V12
set array[104]=V13
set array[105]=V14
set array[106]=V15
set array[107]=V16
set array[108]=H09
set array[109]=PD2
set array[110]=PD3
set array[111]=MMA
set array[112]=MM2
set array[113]=MM3
set array[114]=MD1
set array[115]=HOP
set array[116]=PC2
set array[117]=PCA
set array[118]=ARC
set array[119]=CMD
set array[120]=CMA
set array[121]=C13
set array[122]=C14
set array[123]=C15
set array[124]=C16
set array[125]=CMA
set array[126]=CNS
set array[127]=CN2
set array[128]=POR
set array[129]=PO2
set array[130]=PTK
set array[131]=S99
set array[132]=S00
set array[133]=CED
set array[134]=UGL
set array[135]=UNH
set array[136]=LEA
set array[137]=LEB
set array[138]=2ED
set array[139]=3ED
set array[140]=4ED
set array[141]=5ED
set array[142]=6ED
set array[143]=7ED
set array[144]=8ED
set array[145]=9ED
set array[146]=10E
set array[147]=M10
set array[148]=M11
set array[149]=M12
set array[150]=M13
set array[151]=M14
set array[152]=M15
set array[153]=ORI
set n=0
:start
if NOT !n!==154 (
echo http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?page=2&output=spoiler&method=visual&action=advanced&set=%5B%22!array[%n%]!%22%5D
set /A n=n+1
goto :start
)
echo done!
```

Comment: `&` and `%` have special meaning in cmd. Escape them with a `^` so `&` becomes `^&`. You can enclose the entire string in `"` and the ampersands will be ignored. But the percents signs may expand if they can. EG %22 will be treated as the second parameter to the batch file, if one if present.

Comment: So if i enclose in " it will stop trying to read them as commands? also how with the escapes effect using the url with wget for windows? also I have not set anything to %22 so is there risk of expansion if i don't set anything to that value?

Comment: I can't speak to the specifics of wget but nearly all programming languages remove quotes when giving it to the program. So your program would see the entire string at *parameter 1* as above.

Comment: Ok thank you very much I haven't touched batch in years and never messed with urls before I also found the %22 were from the text replacing [ and ] with %5B%22 and %22%5D  respectively for some reason

Comment: They are illegal characters so get changed into their hex code.